# Printing out each element of an ArrayList without repeating elements and re-printing again

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I am trying to write a code that sends output to another client via a socket. This code basically takes an input as an ArrayList and sends each element of the list one by one to the client without repeating elements. After going through all the elements, it re=populates the list and sends the elements again one by one. I have tried several different codes for this but my elements continue to repeat. Here is my code

```
ArrayList<String> listCopy = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(!list.isEmpty()) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num = random.nextInt(list.size());
        element = list.get(num);
        listCopy.add(element);
        output.println(element);
        for (String copy2 : listCopy) {
            if (list.contains(copy2)) {
                list.remove(copy2);
        }
    }
   if(list.size()==0) {

      for(String copy2 : listCopy) {
            list.add(copy2); }
        }



}
```

Basically my logic for this is that I have a list I get a random element from it and send the element. I make sure to add this element to the copy and then I iterate through the copy after adding each element to the copy and remove the element from the orginal end. In the end once my original list is zero I re-add the elements back and go through the process again.

Answer (score 1):

So, every time through your loop, you check every element you've processed against every element in the original list.  All you need is a Set rather than a List.  A Set is also a collection, but it does not have duplicates.  It's true that a Set will not provide the sort of random access that a List does, so you might want to still have a List, but to get rid of duplicates, all you need is to dump all the values into a Set and then dump the values back into a new List, and you have a new List with the same values but no duplicates.

Comment: The things is that my original list I am using already has no duplicates. I am trying to be able to send elements from the original list one by one without repeating them and doing so randomly.

Comment: How about this?  Just start by cloning your list.  Then send out from the cloned list, removing each one as you send it.  When your list is empty, clone the original again.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that when your have a collection of objects, such as a `List`, the objects are not really *in* the collection. The collection is merely a bunch of *references* (pointers) leading to he objects that reside elsewhere in memory.

So, multiple lists can each have an entry for the same object, each having a reference to the sample specific object sitting somewhere in memory. You can even duplicate a list, resisting in two lists where each element in one list points to the same object as he counterpart element in the other list. You can even delete some elements, some references, without any impact on the object itself.

So rather than manipulating your list, duplicate. Then work on hat duplicate list, keeping the original intact.

Use a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) rather than an `ArrayList` when doing multiple deletions.

```
List< Person > personsOriginal = List.of( alice, bob, carol, david ) ;
List< Person > persons = new LinkedList<>( personsOriginal ) ;

while( ! persons.isEmpty() ) {
    int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , persons.size() ) ;
    Person person = persons.remove( randomIndex ) ;
    … // Wants to get out of hear head.         
}
```